# NullPointerException in Netbeans

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have the following code that is facing a NullPointerException error in Netbeans. The code is actually written for use with a GUI using java frames. But I edited to only use it from the cmd. I have ran through the codes but couldn't find out why the error is popping up. Can anyone highlight whats the problem here? The error message indicated the line of error is at the assignment of threeDPixMod and oneDPix

```
package image_processor;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class ImgMod02a
{
  BufferedImage rawImg;
  BufferedImage buffImage;
  int imgCols;//Number of horizontal pixels
  int imgRows;//Number of rows of pixels

  static String theProcessingClass = "C:/Users/Faiz/Documents/NetBeansProjects/image_processor/src/image_processor/ImgMod35a.java";

  static String theImgFile = "C:/Users/Faiz/Desktop/DCT/ibrahim2.jpg";

  int[][][] threeDPix;
  int[][][] threeDPixMod;
  int[] oneDPix;

  //Reference to the image processing object.
  ImgIntfc02 imageProcessingObject;
  //-------------------------------------------//

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    //Display name of processing program and
    // image file.
    System.out.println("Processing program: " + theProcessingClass);
    System.out.println("Image file: " + theImgFile);


    //Instantiate an object of this class
    ImgMod02a obj = new ImgMod02a();
  }//end main
  //-------------------------------------------//

  public ImgMod02a() throws IOException
  {

    rawImg = ImageIO.read(new File(theImgFile));
    imgCols = rawImg.getWidth();
    imgRows = rawImg.getHeight();

    threeDPixMod = imageProcessingObject.processImg(threeDPix,imgRows,imgCols);

    oneDPix = convertToOneDim(threeDPixMod,imgCols,imgRows);

    oneDPix = new int[imgCols * imgRows];

    //Create an empty BufferedImage object
    buffImage = new BufferedImage(imgCols,imgRows,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw Image into BufferedImage
    Graphics g = buffImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(rawImg, 0, 0, null);

    //Convert the BufferedImage to numeric pixel
    // representation.
    DataBufferInt dataBufferInt = (DataBufferInt)buffImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    oneDPix = dataBufferInt.getData();


    threeDPix = convertToThreeDim(oneDPix,imgCols,imgRows);


    try
    {
      imageProcessingObject = (ImgIntfc02)Class.forName("image_processor.ImgMod35a").newInstance();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }//end catch
  }//end constructor
  //===========================================//


  int[][][] convertToThreeDim(int[] oneDPix,int imgCols,int imgRows)
  {
    //Create the new 3D array to be populated
    // with color data.
    int[][][] data = new int[imgRows][imgCols][4];

    for(int row = 0;row < imgRows;row++){
      //Extract a row of pixel data into a
      // temporary array of ints
      int[] aRow = new int[imgCols];
      for(int col = 0; col < imgCols;col++)
      {
        int element = row * imgCols + col;
        aRow[col] = oneDPix[element];
      }//end for loop on col

      for(int col = 0;col < imgCols;col++)
      {
        //Alpha data
        data[row][col][0] = (aRow[col] >> 24) & 0xFF;
        //Red data
        data[row][col][1] = (aRow[col] >> 16) & 0xFF;
        //Green data
        data[row][col][2] = (aRow[col] >> 8) & 0xFF;
        //Blue data
        data[row][col][3] = (aRow[col]) & 0xFF;
      }//end for loop on col
    }//end for loop on row
    return data;
  }//end convertToThreeDim
  //-------------------------------------------//

  final int[] convertToOneDim(int[][][] data,int imgCols,int imgRows)
  {
    int[] oneDPix = new int[imgCols * imgRows * 4];

    for(int row = 0,cnt = 0;row < imgRows;row++)
    {
      for(int col = 0;col < imgCols;col++){
        oneDPix[cnt] = ((data[row][col][0] << 24)& 0xFF000000)| ((data[row][col][1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)| ((data[row][col][2] << 8) & 0x0000FF00)| ((data[row][col][3]) & 0x000000FF);
        cnt++;
      }//end for loop on col
    }//end for loop on row

    return oneDPix;
  }//end convertToOneDim
}//end ImgMod02a.java class
```

The processImg is a method from an interface

```
    interface ImgIntfc02
    {
      int[][][] processImg(int[][][] threeDPix,
                           int imgRows,
                           int imgCols);
    }
```

This is the line that is causing the error

```
threeDPixMod = imageProcessingObject.processImg(threeDPix,imgRows,imgCols);
```

But when I try commenting out the line, other lines appear to have the NullPointerException error as well.

The error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   image_processor.ImgMod02a.(ImgMod02a.java:48)
>   at
>   image_processor.ImgMod02a.main(ImgMod02a.java:37)

Comment: What line is line 48? The error message is telling you where the problem happened.

Comment: I have edited, highlighting the line that is causing the error. I tried commenting out the line, but the error keep occurring for other lines. Is there something wrong with the declarations

Answer (score 2):

```
  public ImgMod02a() throws IOException
  {

    rawImg = ImageIO.read(new File(theImgFile));
    imgCols = rawImg.getWidth();
    imgRows = rawImg.getHeight();

    threeDPixMod = imageProcessingObject.processImg(threeDPix,imgRows,imgCols);

    // ... Other Stuff ...

    try
    {
      imageProcessingObject = (ImgIntfc02)Class.forName("image_processor.ImgMod35a").newInstance();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }//end catch
  }//end constructor
```

You are trying to use `imageProcessingObject` a few lines into the constructor. However, initializing `imageProcessingObject` is the last thing you do in the constructor. You always need to initialize a variable before you can call a method on an object.

Answer (score 2):

YOU haven't initialized `threeDPix` inside contructor.

while writing:

```
   ImgMod02a obj = new ImgMod02a();
```

the constructor is being called:

```
public ImgMod02a() throws IOException
  {
     //your code
}
```

inside which you have written:

```
 threeDPixMod = imageProcessingObject.processImg(threeDPix,imgRows,imgCols);
```

You need to initialize a variable before using it!